Are questions about education theory on topic here?
I've recently read Mindstorms by Seymour Papert and I'm currently reading The Educated Mind by Kieran Egan. I've got a few questions about the intersection between these two and their application. Although somewhat related to developmental psychology, I'm not sure if educational theory is on topic here. If it's not on topic here, what other site should I go to?

Speaking as a user I'd like it to be on topic; Speaking as a moderator I'll let the community weigh in.

Yes, I think that most aspects of educational theory would be on topic. In particular topics related to how people learn, how best to educate, etc. are on topic. We aim to take a scientific approach to answering such questions on this site.
There are plenty of relevant tags that might give you a flavour for what is considered on topic:

educational-psychology
learning
developmental-psychology


Anything that has to do with scientifically explaining behavior is on-topic for CogSci.SE, as far as I'm concerned.
